# Java/Kotlin How do I iterate through a String, so that Combining characters stay with their base characters?

Tags: java, kotlin, utf-16

I am attempting to iterate the following string:

mɔ̃tr

But no matter what I do, it always ends up getting processed as:

m ɔ  ̃ t r

The tilde seems to detach from the reversed c.

One of my first attempts was to do the following:

```
"mɔ̃tr".map {
    print(it)
}
```

But the tilde would not stay with the reversed c.

I saw suggestions for the following iterator:

```
fun codePoints(string: String): Iterable<String> {
    return object : Iterable<String> {
        override fun iterator(): MutableIterator<String> {
            return object : MutableIterator<String> {
                var nextIndex = 0
                override fun hasNext(): Boolean {
                    return nextIndex < string.length
                }

                override fun next(): String {
                    val result = string.codePointAt(nextIndex)
                    nextIndex += Character.charCount(result)
                    return String(Character.toChars(result))
                }

                override fun remove() {
                    throw UnsupportedOperationException()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But this gave the same output as the previous example.

I have been stuck on this seemingly simple problem for a day now, I just want to process this string as though it had 4 characters, not 5.

Any tips?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that your string really has 5 code points, so what you're asking in the title is different from what is in the body of your question. What you really want to know seems like "How do I iterate through a String, so that Combining characters stay with their base characters?" Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, I will update my question to reflect that intention, thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"ɔ̃" consists of *two* Unicode code points. This is why the code point iterator you showed still treats ɔ̃ as separate.

"ɔ̃" is a single [grapheme cluster](https://unicode.org/reports/tr29/#Grapheme_Cluster_Boundaries). To iterate over those, you need a [`java.text.BreakIterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/text/BreakIterator.html). In the documentation, there is an example that shows you how.

```
public static void printEachForward(BreakIterator boundary, String source) {
    int start = boundary.first();
    for (int end = boundary.next();
         end != BreakIterator.DONE;
         start = end, end = boundary.next()) {
         System.out.println(source.substring(start,end));
    }
}
```

In Kotlin, you can write an extension function on `String` that returns you a `Sequence` of the grapheme clusters.

```
fun String.graphemeClusterSequence() = sequence {
    val iterator = BreakIterator.getCharacterInstance()
    iterator.setText(this@graphemeClusterSequence)
    var start = iterator.first()
    var end = iterator.next()
    while (end != BreakIterator.DONE) {
        yield(this@graphemeClusterSequence.substring(start, end))
        start = end
        end = iterator.next()
    }
}
```

Now `"mɔ̃tr".graphemeClusterSequence().forEach { println(it) }` prints:

```
m
ɔ̃
t
r
```

Comment: Adding the two code point for reference [Latin Small Letter Open O 'ɔ'](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+0254), [Combining Tilde '◌̃'](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+0303)

Comment: This is a great answer, but I am on kmm which doesn't seem to support break iterator

Comment: @LoganMurphy Your question does not mention KMM. It does mention Java, which suggests that you are targeting the JVM. As far as I know, there is no platform independent solution for this. You would need to write different code for each platform you want to support.

Comment: @LoganMurphy For iOS, for example, I would write this as a Swift function that can be called from Kotlin. This is because Swift `Character` already represents a grapheme cluster, so it is very convenient.